# Responsive menu won't sticky properly

Tags: css, wordpress

kwpei.com is my first client site and I have several issues with the menu I can't figure out. The responsive menu won't go sticky properly no matter what I try. I've even tried using a plugin but that makes it flash and flicker till it passes the header image. As well as making it sticky it also needs to close once an item is selected from it which it currently doesnt do.

The second issue is as the primary nav collapses Home and lore get covered by the small site title to the left.

I really don't know what code to include here when you will be looking at the code in inspector but I know the site will make me include some... I hope someone can lend me some help.

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

.nav-primary,
.nav-primary.fixed {
    /* set the position to fixed */
    position: fixed;
    /* make the menu stick at the top */
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a live URL for the site?

Comment: www.kwpei.com, I mentioned that in the top line of the question.

Comment: You can try and use the dreaded !important tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further down in your CSS file (line 2082) you have another declaration for your position attribute for .nav-primary.fixed that sets it to static rather than fixed. That is overriding the code you posted.

Comment: when I comment that line 2082 code out the site defaults to the mobile menu for the normal site, any ideas?

Comment: I just commented it out through the DOM inspector and it doesn't do that for me. Anything above 800px shows the regular menu. What browser are you using?

Comment: Ive just commented it out and left it so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I see it now. You forgot to comment out the closing bracket.

You have:

`/*.nav-primary.fixed {
  position: static; */
 }`

But it should be:

`/*.nav-primary.fixed {
  position: static; 
 } */`

Comment: AWESOME... now any idea how to make the responsive menu close on item selection?

Comment: you're going to have to add to your javascript/jquery. in your global.js file you have a listener that slides the mobile menu up and down when you click the hamburger icon.  

`$(".responsive-menu-icon").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".nav-primary .genesis-nav-menu, .nav-secondary .genesis-nav-menu").slideToggle();
 });`

You'll need to use something similar to be called when they click the elements you want to close the mobile menu.

Comment: Thank you again... and if you get a moment... how do I stop Home and Lore from sliding under the menu as it collapses down to 800px?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125667/discussion-between-patrick-h-and-redtail).